# Read jpg comression quality

Tags: python, python-3.x, jpeg, python-imaging-library, image-compression

**Update:**

After further reading I found out that the compression is not only not stored in the image header but also that the quality number is basically meaningless because different programs have a different approach to it. I'm still leaving this here in case anybody has a very clever solution to the problem.

I did write a log and have an approach writing the time I last compressed an image comparing it to the last modified time on the file, though I still would like to solve the problem of getting the quality for other images that I can't just get by time modified.

**Original question:**

I have a small `Python` script that walks trough certain folders and compresses certain `.jpg` files to 60 quality utilizing the pillow library.

It works however in a second iteration it would compress all the images that already were compressed.

So is there a way toe get the compression or quality the `.jpg` currently has so I can skip the file if it was already compressed?

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
from PIL import Image

start_directory = ".\\test"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_directory):
    for f in files:

        try:
            with Image.open(join(root, f)) as im:
                if im.quality > 60: # <= something like this
                    im.save(join(root, f),optimize=True,quality=60)
            im.close() # <= not sure if necessary
        except IOError:
            pass
```

Comment: I think this task is a pretty bad idea, because JPEG's [generation loss](https://flif.info/lossy.html) will far outweigh the difference in save quality you choose. [jpegtran](https://linux.die.net/man/1/jpegtran) can do some lossless optimization of JPEGs though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way this **might** be solved. You could use **bits per pixel** to check your jpeg compression rate.

As I understand it, the JPEG "quality" metric is a number from 0-100 where 100 represents lossless and 0 is maximum compression. As you say, the actual compression details will vary from encoder to encoder and (probably) from pixel block to pixel block (macroblocks?). Applying 60 to an image will reduce the image quality but it will also reduce the file **size**, presumably to 60% of its original size.

**Edit:** the above paragraph is my interpretation of the [Pillow documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html) but do note that the Pillow documentation uses "quality" primarily as a parameter for saving images - there's no documentation that I can see for Pillow reading the "quality" parameter in from a file, so it is safe to assume that in this circumstance, the value of `im.quality` is likely meaningless (or, rather, completely dependent on the interpretation of encoder that last changed the JPEG quality).

All your images will probably have different dimensions. What you want to look at is **bits per pixel**.

The question is: why do you compress at quality factor 60 in the first place? Is it correct for all your images? Are you trying to achieve a specific file size? Or are you happy just to make them all smaller?

If you, instead, aim for a specific number of bits per pixel, then your check just becomes a calculation of file size divided by number of pixels in the image and check this against your desired bits per pixel. If it’s bigger, apply compression.

Of course, you’ll then have to be slightly more clever than selecting quality factor 60. Presumably 60 either means 60% of original file size or (more likely) it’s some internal setting. If it’s the former, you can calculate a new value simply enough. If it’s the latter, you may need to use trial and improvement to get the desired file size.

Comment: This is not correct: " the JPEG "quality" metric is a number from 0-100 where 100 represents lossless and 0 is maximum compression."

Comment: Thanks. This is only a minimal example. I do have exclusions like a gitignore and also command line arguments for quality etc. I’m not doing this to good photos but to hundreds of photos shot on cheap cameras surveying construction sites purely for documentary purposes. They take like 90% of our NAS space. Bringing them down to a fraction of their original size without visible loss at a screen when not zoomed is enough in this case. Maybe resizing and compressing a higher quality may be better for some cases. This is nothing professional. I’m just an engineer who likes to code at weekends.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the  impossible here. JPEG "quality" depends upon two factors. First, the sampling of the components. Second, the selection of quantization tables.

Some JPEG encoders have "quality" settings but these could do anything. Some use ranges of 0 .. 100 Others use 0..4. I've seen 0..8. I've seen :"high", "Medium", "Low."

You could conceivably look at the sampling rates in the frame and you could compare the quantization tables and compare them to some baseline tables of your own to make a "quality" evaluation.